# Ruby convert non-printable characters into numbers

Tags: ruby, regex, string, non-printing-characters

I have a string with non-printable characters.

What I am currently doing is replacing them with a tilde using:

```
string.gsub!(/^[:print:]]/, "~")
```

However, I would actually like to convert them to their integer value.

I tried this, but it always outputs `0`

```
string.gsub!(/[^[:print:]]/, "#{$1.to_i}")
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub), [String#gsub!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) accept optional block. The return value of the block is used for substitution.

```
"\x01Hello\x02".gsub(/[^[:print:]]/) { |x| x.ord }
# => "1Hello2"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Object#inspect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-inspect) is also an option if you just need to output string with non-printable characters to log or for debug purposes.

```
puts "\x01Hello\x02".inspect
# => "\u0001Hello\u0002"
```