# Combining a string with capitalized hex seems to erase the first string

Tags: ruby, string, upcase

I'm trying to concat a SQL query string and a hex string that should be capitalized. `hURL -X -s` takes a string or file and coverts it to hex.

```
cmd = "/root/Desktop/pentest/tools/hURL/hURL -X -s " +
  md5_got.chomp.delete("\n").to_s
md5_tohex = `#{cmd}`  
md5_where = md5_tohex.chomp.delete("\n").to_s
```

At this point, `md5_where` is:

`1b5b316d34303339613365663766633739653461646236306234336163313038643634381b5b306d`

I need this hex capitalized. I did both of these in all permutations including leaving out the `to_s` and the `!`:

```
md5_where.upcase! 
md5_where.to_s!
```

I try and combine my query and my hex value:

```
sql_comp = "SELECT word FROM captcha_rbow WHERE hex(md5) = " + md5_where
puts sql_comp
puts '###
abort()
```

This is what I get:

```
                         1B5B316D653...B306D
```

Leading spaces equal to the length of the SQL query and the upstring variable printed on the screen with no trace of the SQL query

If I take `md5_where`, I get this, which is as it should be:

```
SELECT word FROM captcha_rbow WHERE hex(md5) =
```

Why does this clobber the text?
Here is full script
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'sqlite3'

```
open('GOT_captcha.png', 'wb') do |file|
  file << open('http://192.168.56.101/captcha/example5/captcha.png').read
end

cmd = "/root/Desktop/pentest/tools/hURL/hURL -m -s -f GOT_captcha.png"
md5orig = `#{cmd}`

cmd = "/root/Desktop/pentest/tools/hURL/hURL -X -s " +  md5orig.chomp.delete("\n").to_s
puts cmd
md5_tohex = `#{cmd}`  
md5_where = md5_tohex.to_s
puts md5_where

sql_comp = "SELECT word FROM captcha_rbow WHERE (hex(md5)) = " + md5_where.upcase
puts sql_comp  
#THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS

begin
    db = SQLite3::Database.open( "akad_web2" )
    sql_comp = "SELECT word FROM captcha_rbow  WHERE hex(md5) = '" + md5_where.upcase + "';"
    puts sql_comp
    stm = db.prepare sql_comp
    rs = stm.execute        
    row = rs.next
    puts row.to_s
rescue SQLite3::Exception => e    
        puts "Exception occurred"
        puts e
ensure
        stm.close if stm
        db.close if db
end
abort()
```

NOTE - input is an image file (a captcha generated via RMagick with a known set of possible strings) to generate an MD5 rainbow table.

This is the output:

```
/root/Desktop/pentest/tools/hURL/hURL -X -s 4039a3ef7fc79e4adb60b43ac108d648
1b5b316d34303339613365663766633739653461646236306234336163313038643634381b5b306d
                                                 1B5B316D34303339613365663766633739653461646236306234336163313038643634381B5B306D
                                                 1B5B316D34303339613365663766633739653461646236306234336163313038643634381B5B306D';

root@kali:~/Desktop/Akademy_webpentest_2#
```

Comment: please post your full script with an example input.

Comment: What's the problem? `upcase` works exactly as it should: http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/12ed3

Comment: `to_s!` is not valid Ruby - are you using some library that implements that method for strings?

Comment: Don’t run a shell to run an external program to encode a string in hex… `md5_got.chomp.unpack('H*')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem: by default `hURL` **colors the output with ANSI  escape sequences**.

Example:

```
> hURL -X -s "test" | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 31 6d 37 34 36 35  37 33 37 34 1b 5b 30 6d  |.[1m74657374.[0m|
```

So what you're getting back to your Ruby script inside your `md5_tohex` variable is an ANSI escaped string.
This is why everything seems to behave strangely from that point forward.

Run `hURL` with the `--nocolor` option to disable this behavior:

```
> hURL -X -s --nocolor "test" | hexdump -C
00000000  37 34 36 35 37 33 37 34                           |74657374|
```

Further evidence of the problem:

```
irb> s = `hURL -X -s "xyz"`
=> "\e[1m78797a\e[0m"
irb> s.upcase
=> "\e[1M78797A\e[0M"
irb> puts s.upcase
                                  # <- exactly nothing is printed    
=> nil
```

By using `--nocolor` everything is resolved:

```
irb> s = `hURL -X -s --nocolor "xyz"`
=> "78797a"
irb> puts s.upcase
78797A
=> nil
```

Comment: Is there some way to strip away any special characters that may have embedded themselves into a string? Thx

Comment: @DanMiller Have a look at these for some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146704/ruby-convert-non-printable-characters-into-numbers  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530038/how-to-remove-non-printable-invisible-characters-in-ruby